# HSQLDB connection using nodejs

Tags: node.js, hsqldb

How can I connect to HSQLDB using nodejs. Any good links or sample codes will be useful. I have gone through [this page](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hsqldb/hsqldb_connect.htm) which explains how to connect to hsqldb using java programming. I want to achieve the same using nodejs.

Answer (score 3):

There is a node.js package for JDBC connection to HSQLDB. The example given includes the connection URL for an HSQLDB server instance.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/jdbc