# Connecting from Node.js to a JDBC driver

Tags: python, java, node.js, npm, jdbc

I am trying to connect from Node.js to a [JDBC driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51647704/hsqldb-connection-using-nodejs). I follow the instructions here:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/jdbc

I downloaded the project from [Github](https://github.com/CraZySacX/node-jdbc) and in the project directory I try to install it:

```
npm i --python="/usr/local/bin/python3.11" jdbc
```

However, this did not work out. I am getting the following errors which I find hard to understand:

```
me@me:~/PROJECTS/node-jdbc-master$ npm i --python="/usr/local/bin/python3.11" jdbc
npm WARN deprecated bind-obj-methods@2.0.1: do not use this version, it is broken
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated lolex@6.0.0: lolex has been renamed to @sinonjs/fake-timers. No API changes made. Please use the new package instead
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated nodeunit@0.11.3: you are strongly encouraged to use other testing options
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /home/me/PROJECTS/node-jdbc-master/node_modules/java
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! make: Entering directory '/home/me/PROJECTS/node-jdbc-master/node_modules/java/build'
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/nodejavabridge_bindings/src/java.o
npm ERR! nodejavabridge_bindings.target.mk:124: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/nodejavabridge_bindings/src/java.o' failed
npm ERR! make: Leaving directory '/home/me/PROJECTS/node-jdbc-master/node_modules/java/build'
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.0.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@17.9.0 | linux | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.11.0 found at "/usr/local/bin/python3.11"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /usr/local/bin/python3.11
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/home/me/PROJECTS/node-jdbc-master/node_modules/java/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/home/me/.cache/node-gyp/17.9.0/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/home/me/.cache/node-gyp/17.9.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/home/me/.cache/node-gyp/17.9.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/home/me/PROJECTS/node-jdbc-master/node_modules/java',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp info spawn make
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
npm ERR! In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:2884:0,
npm ERR!                  from ../src/java.h:9,
npm ERR!                  from ../src/java.cpp:1:
npm ERR! ../../nan/nan_typedarray_contents.h: In constructor ‘Nan::TypedArrayContents<T>::TypedArrayContents(v8::Local<v8::Value>)’:
npm ERR! ../../nan/nan_typedarray_contents.h:34:43: error: ‘class v8::ArrayBuffer’ has no member named ‘GetContents’
npm ERR!        data   = static_cast<char*>(buffer->GetContents().Data()) + byte_offset;
npm ERR!                                            ^
npm ERR! make: *** [Release/obj.target/nodejavabridge_bindings/src/java.o] Error 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-146-generic
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /home/me/PROJECTS/node-jdbc-master/node_modules/java
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v17.9.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.0.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/me/.npm/_logs/2022-04-19T18_56_54_389Z-debug-0.log
me@me:~/PROJECTS/node-jdbc-master$
```

**What am I doing wrong here?**

Is the Java version I am using not supported?

```
$ java -version
java version "11.0.1" 2018-10-16 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13-LTS, mixed mode)
```

Comment: from reading the error message it seems that the v8 version you have is not supported by the version of [https://www.npmjs.com/package/jdbc]

Comment: How can I change the v8 version?

Comment: You don't 'connect to a JDBC driver'. You use JDBC to connect to a database server.

Answer (score 0):

Some node modules do not come compiled.  They are pure source code, allowing them to work in different architectures.  The catch: they need to be compiled.  That's what node-gyp is trying to do.  It in turn calls the 'make' module, which is used to compile C code.  At this point it needs the appropriate C compile libraries.  You are missing those.

Where to get these can be tricky.  I usually download and install the C++ runtime environment (just google it), and that usually does the trick.  I've been told installing Visual Studio works, too.  Apparently the key file you need is MSBuild.exe.

So make sure you have the correct version of python installed, node-gyp installed, make installed, and C++ installed (either the C++ runtime, or you can try the g++ module, which I have never used).  It looks like the 'java' module is triggering this process, so check [the java modules documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/java).

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39739626/what-is-node-gyp).